# Как сохранить массив в базу данных?

Tags: java, mysql, коллекции

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли сохранить массив с данными (Java) в MySQL?

Если возможно, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень нужно, то можно сериализовать его...
А вообще, лучше каждый элемент записывать в новую строку таблицы с общими ID для каждого массива.

```
arr1 = {1, 2, 3}
arr2 = {3, 5, 2, 4, 1}

table 'arrays':
-----------
ID | value |
------------
1  | 1     |
1  | 2     |
1  | 3     |
2  | 3     |
2  | 5     |
2  | 2     |
2  | 4     |
2  | 1     |
------------
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.